# how to retrieve a job information LSF archive

Tags: linux, lsf

We execute our job application through bsub command in Linux 
OS. 
when the job completes, what is the command to retrieve the job information from the LSF archive. i know there is command like bacct jobNo. But it does not retrieve the information.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`bacct` retrieves summary information about sets of finished jobs for the purposes of accounting -- it gives you info like average turnaround time, resource usage etc.

I think what you might be looking for is `bhist -l <jobid>`, which will give you the historical information about that job's submission and execution (similar to `bjobs -l` but more detailed and works for jobs that finished long ago).